# How to change which microphone a website is using in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I enabled microphone permission to a website in Chrome. Then I realized Chrome was using the wrong microphone by default. I changed the default microphone in Chrome’s settings but the website is still using the wrong one.

When I allow microphone permission on new websites it uses the correct one that I updated in Chrome’s settings.

When I click on the microphone icon in the address bar while on the website in question it has a drop down with the wrong microphone selected but the drop down is disabled / grayed out for some reason. How do I fix this?

Comment: This problem appears to not be specific to Chrome.  Does Anyone know if it is specific to Windows?

Comment: I’ve had this problem on Mac Chrome too. And Edge is basically Chrome as it’s based on Chromium now.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I had to go to Windows audio settings (NOT in Control Panel) and under the microphone section I disabled the incorrect microphone that was getting used (Steam Stream Microphone). Then I restarted Chrome.

This same issue happened in Microsoft Edge browser (since it’s Chromium based now) and the same fix for Chrome worked there too.

Here are all the things I tried that didn’t help:

- delete all Chrome cache
- remove permissions for the website in question and re-authorize microphone permission
- reinstall Chrome (which means I’m guessing that this setting is stored somewhere that uninstalling doesn’t clean up)